# Pandas: Chained assignments

Tags: python, pandas, copy, chained-assignment

I have been reading this [link](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) on "Returning a view versus a copy". I do not really get how the **chained assignment** concept in Pandas works and how the usage of `.ix()`, `.iloc()`, or `.loc()` affects it.

I get the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warnings for the following lines of code, where `data` is a Panda dataframe and `amount` is a column (Series) name in that dataframe:

```
data['amount'] = data['amount'].astype(float)

data["amount"].fillna(data.groupby("num")["amount"].transform("mean"), inplace=True)

data["amount"].fillna(mean_avg, inplace=True)
```

Looking at this code, is it obvious that I am doing something suboptimal? If so, can you let me know the replacement code lines?

I am aware of the below warning and like to think that the warnings in my case are false positives:

> The chained assignment warnings / exceptions are aiming to inform the
> user of a possibly invalid assignment. There may be false positives;
> situations where a chained assignment is inadvertantly reported.

**EDIT :** the code leading to the first copy warning error.

```
data['amount'] = data.apply(lambda row: function1(row,date,qty), axis=1) 
data['amount'] = data['amount'].astype(float)

def function1(row,date,qty):
    try:
        if(row['currency'] == 'A'):
            result = row[qty]
        else:
            rate = lookup[lookup['Date']==row[date]][row['currency'] ]
            result = float(rate) * float(row[qty])
        return result
    except ValueError: # generic exception clause
        print "The current row causes an exception:"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The point of the `SettingWithCopy` is to warn the user that you *may* be doing something that will not update the original data frame as one might expect.

Here, `data` is a dataframe, possibly of a single dtype (or not). You are then taking a reference to this `data['amount']` which is a Series, and updating it. This probably works in your case because you are returning the same dtype of data as existed.

However it *could* create a copy which updates a copy of `data['amount']` which you would not see; Then you would be wondering why it is not updating.

Pandas returns a copy of an object in almost all method calls. The `inplace` operations are a convience operation which work, but in general are not clear that data is being modified and could potentially work on copies.

Much more clear to do this:

```
data['amount'] = data["amount"].fillna(data.groupby("num")["amount"].transform("mean"))

data["amount"] = data['amount'].fillna(mean_avg)
```

One further plus to working on copies. You can chain operations, this is not possible with `inplace` ones.

e.g.

```
data['amount'] = data['amount'].fillna(mean_avg)*2
```

And just an FYI. `inplace` operations are neither faster nor more memory efficient. my2c they should be banned. But too late on that API.

You can of course turn this off:

```
pd.set_option('chained_assignment',None)
```

Pandas runs with the entire test suite with this set to `raise` (so we know if chaining is happening) on, FYI.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, so I should ideally remove the `inplace` parameters for the 2nd and 3rd warnings. Regarding the 1st one, i.e. `data['amount'] = data['amount'].astype(float)`, what would be a replacement that does not produce the copy warning?

Comment: you must be doing something *before* the astype assignment. can you show more code?

Comment: sure, I added the code to my question.

Comment: can you show ``data.info()`` before this? you should have ``float64`` dtypes already. secondarily, you don't need the apply, you can do something like: ``data[data['currency']!='A','amount']=data['qty']*data['rate']``

Comment: Thanks @Jeff for this solution: pd.set_option('chained_assignment',None) However I'm wondering if this is recommended since I'm always conservative in changing default warning settings...