# Pandas: SettingWithCopyWarning trigger location

Tags: python, pandas

With `SettingWithCopyWarning`, sometimes it refers you to the exact line of code in your module that triggered the warning (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560749/python-pandas-removing-settingwithcopywarning)) and other times it doesn't (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002762/pandas-settingwithcopywarning)).

Short of going through each line of the code (doesn't sound too appealing if you're reviewing hundreds of lines of code), is there a way to pinpoint the line of code that triggered the warning assuming the warning does not return that information?

I wonder if this is a bug in the warning to return a warning without pinpointing the specific code that triggered it.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 415
    self.obj[item] = s
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

**Python 3.4, Pandas 0.15.0**

Answer (score 7):

You can have pandas raise `SettingWithCopyError` instead of `SettingWithCopyWarning` by setting the `mode.chained_assignment` option to `raise` instead of `warn`.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', 'raise')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options