# Copying values between columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with the columns `Name` and `name`.

And I'm doing this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (some condition):
        df['name'][i] = df['Name'][i]
```

But I get this warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

And also it takes a while to run,  it's that  related with the warning?

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['name'].notnull() , 'Name'] = df['name']
```

And very nice explanation of  [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21561061/2901002).

So generally:

```
df.loc[some condition , 'Name'] = df['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use chained assignments.  You should use `.loc`:

```
condition = ... # something that identifies the relevant rows.
df.loc[condition, 'Name'] = df.loc[condition, 'name']
```

Refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments) for more information.

And this is the link to the relevant Pandas documentation ["Why does the assignment when using chained indexing fail!"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail).