# Pandas won't fillna() inplace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill NAs  with "" on 4 specific columns in a data frame that are string/object types. I can assign these columns to a new variable as I fillna(), but when I fillna() inplace the underlying data doesn't change.

```
a_n6 = a_n6[["PROV LAST", "PROV FIRST", "PROV MID", "SPEC NM"]].fillna("")
a_n6
```

gives me:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1542 entries, 0 to 3611
Data columns (total 4 columns):
PROV LAST     1542  non-null values
PROV FIRST    1542  non-null values
PROV MID      1542  non-null values
SPEC NM       1542  non-null values
dtypes: object(4)
```

but

```
a_n6[["PROV LAST", "PROV FIRST", "PROV MID", "SPEC NM"]].fillna("", inplace=True)
a_n6
```

gives me:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1542 entries, 0 to 3611
Data columns (total 7 columns):
NPI           1103  non-null values
PIN           1542  non-null values
PROV FIRST    1541  non-null values
PROV LAST     1542  non-null values
PROV MID      1316  non-null values
SPEC NM       1541  non-null values
flag          439  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(4)
```

It's just one row, but still frustrating. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've also come across some functions where `inplace=True` seems to be ignored. While that's not the issue in your case, it's worth keeping in mind when troubleshooting.

Answer (score 37):

### Use a `dict` as the `value` argument to `fillna()`

As mentioned in the comment by @rhkarls on @Jeff's answer, using `.loc` indexed to a list of columns won't support `inplace` operations, which I too find frustrating.  Here's a workaround.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,np.nan],
                   'b':[6,7,8,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'x':[11,12,13,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'y':[16,np.nan,np.nan,19,np.nan]})
print(df)
#     a    b     x     y
#0  1.0  6.0  11.0  16.0
#1  2.0  7.0  12.0   NaN
#2  3.0  8.0  13.0   NaN
#3  4.0  NaN   NaN  19.0
#4  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Let's say we want to `fillna` for `x` and `y` only, **not** `a` and `b`.

I would expect using `.loc` to work (as in an assignment), but it doesn't, as mentioned earlier:

```
# doesn't work
df.loc[:,['x','y']].fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df) # nothing changed
```

However, the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) says that the `value` argument to `fillna()` can be:

> alternately a dict/Series/DataFrame of values specifying which value to use for each index (for a Series) or column (for a DataFrame). (values not in the dict/Series/DataFrame will not be filled).

It turns out that using a dict of values will work:

```
# works
df.fillna({'x':0, 'y':0}, inplace=True)
print(df)
#     a    b     x     y
#0  1.0  6.0  11.0  16.0
#1  2.0  7.0  12.0   0.0
#2  3.0  8.0  13.0   0.0
#3  4.0  NaN   0.0  19.0
#4  NaN  NaN   0.0   0.0
```

Also, if you have a lot of columns in your subset, you could use a dict comprehension, as in:

```
df.fillna(dict.fromkeys(['x', 'y'], 0), inplace=True) # also works
```

Answer (score 11):

you are filling a copy (which you then can't see)

either:

- don't `fillna` inplace (there is no performance gain from doing something inplace)

for example

```
a_n6[["PROV LAST", "PROV FIRST", "PROV MID", "SPEC NM"]] = a_n6[["PROV LAST", "PROV FIRST", "PROV MID", "SPEC NM"]].fillna("")
```

or preferably

```
a_n6.fillna({'PROV LAST': '', 'PROV FIRST': '',
            'PROV MID': '', 'SPEC NM': ''}, inplace=True)
```

- assign the copy to a new variable first (the `a_n6[[list_of_fileds]]` is a copy in a multi-dtype object), see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

here's a more in-depth explanation 
[Pandas: Chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments/21463854#21463854)

Comment: I thought the inplace argument was supposed to prevent it from filling a copy.  What is the point of the `inplace` arg if it doesn't change the behavior of the function?

Comment: So why is inplace even allowed for fillna()?

Comment: Inplace will work if you use .loc. Inplace should not work if you are working on a copy. See the links that Jeff included. It will not work for a list of fields (e.g. df.loc[:,[list of fields]]), but it will work on a slice or single field. Also see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11984 for some details on this.

Comment: I just ran fillna on a 20Gb dataset, with inplace and got 'not implemented' error. I don't see the rant about 'no performance gain'. I don't have another 20Gb memory to have a temp copy. Inplace would be highly beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

a workaround is to save fillna results in another variable and assign it back like this:

```
na_values_filled = X.fillna(0)
X = na_values_filled
```

My exact example (which I couldn't get to work otherwise) was a case where I wanted to fillna in only the first line of every group. Like this:

```
groups = one_train.groupby("installation_id")
first_indexes_filled = one_train.loc[groups.apply(pd.DataFrame.first_valid_index), 'clicks'].fillna(0)
one_train.loc[groups.apply(pd.DataFrame.first_valid_index), 'clicks'] =  first_indexes_filled
```

My case may be unnecessarily complicated but i think the general "save results, then assign back" method should work as a workaround for the failing inplace=True

Comment: I had to do the same thing - I was using bfill and ffill conditionally, and the introduction of the condition seemed to prevent fillna from working.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer gave me `SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`, so this is what I ended up with. It works and doesn't give any warnings:

```
fill_dict = {x: 0 for x in columns_of_interest}
df.loc[:, columns_of_interest].fillna(fill_dict, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This did get rid of the `SettingWithCopyWarning`, but then the `inplace=True` did not work (`df` did not change).

Answer (score 0):

The "Use a dict as the value argument" answer doesn't work for me, but an easy enough workaround is to use:

```
for n in ["PROV LAST", "PROV FIRST", "PROV MID", "SPEC NM"]:    
    a_n6[n].fillna("", inplace=True)
a_n6
```