# Erratic NaN behaviour in numpy/pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I've been trying to replace missing values in a Pandas dataframe, but without success. I tried the `.fillna` method and also tried to loop through the entire data set, checking each cell and replacing NaNs with a chosen value. However, in both cases, Python executes the script without throwing up any errors, but the NaN values remain.

When I dug a bit deeper, I discovered behaviour that seems erratic to me, best demonstrated with an example:

```
In[ ] X['Smokinginpregnancy'].head() 

Out[ ] 

Index
E09000002          NaN
E09000003     5.216126
E09000004    10.287496
E09000005     3.090379
E09000006     6.080041
Name: Smokinginpregnancy, dtype: float64
```

I know for a fact that the first item in this column is missing and pandas recognises it as NaN. In fact, if I call this item on its own, python tells me it's NaN:

```
In [ ] X['Smokinginpregnancy'][0]
Out [ ]
nan
```

However, when I test whether it's NaN, python returns False.

```
In [ ] X['Smokinginpregnancy'][0] == np.nan
Out [ ] False
```

I suspect  that when `.fillna` is being executed, python checks whether the item is NaN but gets back a False, so it continues, leaving the cell alone.

Does anyone know what's going on? Any solutions? (apart from opening the csv file in excel and then manually replacing the values.)

I'm using Anaconda's Python 3 distribution.

Comment: `df.fillna()` works fine; you just have to assign its output: `df = df.fillna()`. pandas has deprecated using the `inplace` option.

Comment: Or you can use `.isna()`, `.value_counts(dropna=False)` to see if there are NaN's. Never try to compare with equality `== np.nan` because like @Bakuriu says, it always fails. But anyway, pandas has those (vectorized) methods for doing this on an entire series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing:

```
X['Smokinginpregnancy'][0] == np.nan
```

This is *guaranteed* to return `False` because all NaNs compare unequal to everything **by IEEE754 standard**:

```
>>> x = float('nan')
>>> x == x
False
>>> x == 1
False
>>> x == float('nan')
False
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values).
You have to use [`math.isnan`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.isnan) to check for NaNs:

```
>>> math.isnan(x)
True
```

Or [`numpy.isnan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

So use:

```
numpy.isnan(X['Smokinginpregnancy'][0])
```

---

Regarding [`pandas.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) note that this function **returns** the filled array. Maybe you did something like:

```
X.fillna(...)
```

without reassigning `X`? Alternatively you must pass `inplace=True` to mutate the dataframe on which you are calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` in pandas can be checked with the function [pandas.isnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.isnull.html). I created boolean mask and return subset with `NaN` values.

Function [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) can be used for one column `Smokinginpregnancy` ([more info in doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna)):

```
X['Smokinginpregnancy'] = X['Smokinginpregnancy'].fillna('100')
```

or

```
X['Smokinginpregnancy'].fillna('100', inplace=True)
```

**Warning:**
Sometimes `inplace=True` can be ignored, better is not use. - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21998680/2901002), [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10342), [github 3 comments](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6757#issuecomment-39348309).

All together:

```
print X['Smokinginpregnancy'].head() 
#Index
#E09000002          NaN
#E09000003     5.216126
#E09000004    10.287496
#E09000005     3.090379
#E09000006     6.080041

#check NaN in column Smokinginpregnancy by boolean mask
mask = pd.isnull(X['Smokinginpregnancy'])
XNaN = X[mask]
print XNaN
#           Smokinginpregnancy
#Index
#E09000002                 NaN

#use function fillna for column Smokinginpregnancy
#X['Smokinginpregnancy'] = X['Smokinginpregnancy'].fillna('100')
X['Smokinginpregnancy'].fillna('100', inplace=True)
print X
#          Smokinginpregnancy
#Index
#E09000002                100
#E09000003           5.216126
#E09000004            10.2875
#E09000005           3.090379
#E09000006           6.080041
```

More information, why comparison doesn't work:

One has to be mindful that in python (and numpy), the nan's can’t compared for equality, but None's can. Note that Pandas/numpy uses the fact that `np.nan != np.nan`, and treats `None` like `np.nan`. More info in `Bakuriu's` answer.

```
In [11]: None == None
Out[11]: True

In [12]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[12]: False
```

Comment: While this technically shows the OP what to do, it neither explains that the "erratic" behavior is in fact normal and expected (and why), nor why .fillna didn't work in the first place.