# Using np.where, or another broadcasting technique in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a couple of columns that need to have various columns populated depending upon conditions. I wrote out a function, and have been using `df.apply`, however this is obviously exceptionally slow. I'm looking for help in creating a faster way to do the following:

```
def function(df):
    if pd.isnull(df['criteria_column']) == True:
        return df['return_column']
    else:
        return
df['new_column'] = df.apply(function, axis=1)
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
 df['new_column'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['criteria_column'] == True),
                                       df['return_column'], "")
```

However this results in `ValueError: Could not construct Timestamp from argument <type 'bool'>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use indexing instead of apply, it's much faster:

```
df["new_column"] = ""
is_null = pd.isnull(df["criteria_column"])
df["new_column"][is_null] = df["return_column"][is_null] # method 1
```

**For reference sake, here are a few more ways of doing the same thing as the last line:**

```
df["new_column"][is_null] = df["return_column"][is_null] # method 1
df["new_column"].loc[is_null] = df.loc["return_column"].loc[is_null] # method 2
df.loc[is_null, "new_column"] = df.loc[is_null, "return_column"] # method 3, thanks @joris
```

For those curious, methods 1 and 2 access the pandas.Series that is the column, and do selected assignments on them. Note especially that `series[is_null]` ends up calling `series.loc[is_null]` eventually anyway in this instance.

Lastly, method 3 is a convenience method for doing method 2 that removes possible ambiguities, reduces memory used, and will permit assignments after successive chaining. If you're doing complex selection chaining and don't want intermediate copies or want to assign to the selection, that method will likely be better. See [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

Comment: Indeed, but it's better to use `df.loc[is_null, "new_column"]` instead of `df["new_column"][is_null]` to avoid problems with chained assignment.

Comment: iirc, *.loc is much faster, but I find the chained assignment to be much more readable, so I'd prefer it unless there was a hard reason not to. What issues with chained assignment have you come across?

Comment: Explanation in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy, another example on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments. Probably in this case it won't be a problem (but eg if you switch `["new_column"]` and `[is_null]` order, it could be a problem), but because it sometimes causes problems, and it is not always easy to tell when/when not it will cause problems, it is better to try to use the `loc` idiom to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks. For those interested, when I previously used `.apply` for 3 functions, it took ~40 seconds. The `.loc` method takes ~0.2 seconds. 200x faster.