# pandas: df.loc[-1,col] sometimes work and sometimes add extra row with NAN

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. I am trying to modify `name` column value in the last row

I try

```
df.loc[-1,'name'] = "something"
```

this works

Now I filter few rows from the `df` with a query and call it `df_query`

and my last row in `df_query` is

```
    id  name
21  965 kris
```

I check the index `-1`

```
df_query.loc['name'].iloc[-1]
```

it shows "kris"

now on `df_query` i try

```
df_query.loc[-1,'name'] = "something"
```

it adds an extra row instead of replacing `kris` with `something`

```
    id  name
21  965.0 kris
-1  NaN "something"
```

also convers id into `float` from `int`

why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt

later after searching i found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49510469

> Just using iloc[-1, 'a] won't work as -1 is not in the index.

I couldnt understand the reason given above

and says to try:

```
df_query.loc[df_query.loc.index[-1],'name'] = "something"
```

and now it works.

Can someone explain whats happening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select last value of `name` different way - if use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) use `df.index` for last value of index if index values are unique:

```
df.loc[df.index[-1],'name'] = "something"
```

Or if use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) get position of column `name` by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df.iloc[-1,df.columns.get_loc('name')] = "something"
```

---

If use:

```
df.loc[-1,'name'] = "something"
```

Pandas try set row with `index=-1` if exist, else create new row with index `-1`. Problem is if last index has no `-1`, but e.g. first index, it replace not last, but first row.

So is possible use:

```
#tested last value of index
if df.index[-1] == -1:
    #last value is set
    df.loc[-1,'name'] = "something"

#tested all values if index
elif (df.index == -1).any():
    #some value with -1 is set
    df.loc[-1,'name'] = "something"
else:
    #new row with -1 is created
    df.loc[-1,'name'] = "something"
```

Comment: `Pandas try set row with index=-1 if exist, else create new row with index -1.`  then why sometimes it works. How to know if -1 index exists

Comment: @Santhosh - I think for prevent this problem use first or second solution. You can test -1, but  Ithink it is more complicated. Also one problem is if use `df.loc[-1,'name'] = "something"` - it also replace first row if there is `index=-1`

Comment: I am ok if first is the last row (if dataframe contains only one row), but i want to know why its creating new row, and why not it recognizes -1. how do we know that in some dataframes -1 index exists and some does not.

Comment: also I check the index `-1` by `df_query['name'].iloc[-1]` it shows `kris`. Then how that last index has no` -1`.

Comment: `but Ithink it is more complicated.`  can explain the complexity

Comment: @Santhosh - I try modify answer with explain 3 possible outputs depends of `-1`

Comment: one more thing i want to understand is then how come `df_query['name'].iloc[-1]` says  `kris`

Comment: @Santhosh - hmmm, `iloc` test by position, not by index values like `loc`. So it not create new row.

Comment: i am confused what is index in case of loc and index incase of iloc

Comment: @Santhosh if use loc it select by label, so here by - 1, or 21 in sample data. if use iloc there are labels not important to know, only positions. So 0 means for iloc first row, in sample data row with index=21. And similar - 1 means last row, labels should be 1000, 21, -1, 20010-01-01, some string. Any value, because fir iloc not imporatant.

Comment: thank you. Now you clarified me, So basically in loc is just looking for a literal string (nothing to do with position) and iloc (it looks by position). Same answer
found in : [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc)
`A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the index, and never as an integer position along the index).`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`df.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) to pick the last row of dataframe and then replace the value of `name` column with `something`:

```
df_query.tail(1)['name'] = 'something'
```

**Example:**

```
In [629]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [630]: df
Out[630]: 
     id  name
21  965  kris

In [631]: df.tail(1)['name'] = 'something'

In [632]: df
Out[632]: 
     id       name
21  965  something
```

Comment: I am not getting the warning.

Comment: Ok, I use only `df.tail(1)['name'] = 'something'` with `print (df)`. So no modification after `df.tail(1)['name'] = 'something'`. Interesting.

Comment: @jezrael I've added example. Please check. I don't get any warnings and the output is as expected.

Comment: Tested now and working without this error.