# How to combine live data with historical data in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I retrieve data from binance. In my dataframe I have historical data from the last hour in minute bars. I also have a column with the live avg price (df.price_line). This column has the live price on all rows.

```
                  time     high      low    close       atr        sma signal       ROC  price_line  distance  volatility
50 2021-07-03 10:54:00  2196.00  2199.65  2195.01  3.505200  2191.8358      -  0.213209      2205.6       NaN         NaN
51 2021-07-03 10:55:00  2198.86  2199.81  2196.82  3.597686  2191.9582      -  0.438913      2205.6       NaN         NaN
52 2021-07-03 10:56:00  2197.14  2197.14  2195.14  3.363565  2192.0720      -  0.365774      2205.6       NaN         NaN
53 2021-07-03 10:57:00  2195.52  2197.50  2195.00  3.291882  2192.1594      -  0.352032      2205.6       NaN         NaN
54 2021-07-03 10:58:00  2197.44  2197.44  2195.15  3.231033  2192.2454      -  0.313945      2205.6       NaN         NaN
55 2021-07-03 10:59:00  2196.97  2197.33  2195.67  3.155960  2192.3506      -  0.200797      2205.6       NaN         NaN
56 2021-07-03 11:00:00  2195.96  2198.00  2195.91  3.096962  2192.4422      -  0.088880      2205.6       NaN         NaN
57 2021-07-03 11:01:00  2197.00  2199.88  2196.65  3.159322  2192.5432      -  0.107552      2205.6       NaN         NaN
58 2021-07-03 11:02:00  2198.94  2201.99  2198.01  3.315085  2192.6034      -  0.121165      2205.6       NaN         NaN
59 2021-07-03 11:03:00  2201.31  2215.79  2201.30  4.348293  2192.7606      -  0.241348      2205.6
```

In the last row the close price is based on the minute data. The price line updates with the websocket data from binance in seconds intervals.

How can I update the last df.close row (# 59) in real time based on df.price_line?
I tried it like this:

```
df['close'].iloc[-1] = df.price_line
```

But I get a warning and the df is not working:

```
a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a dataframe
```

When I suppress the warning the dataframe is not working either

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160385/change-an-element-in-the-last-row-of-a-dataframe)

Taking a look at it, it seems that you could do:

```
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('close')] = df.iloc[-1]['price_line']
```