# Pandas get the age from a date (example: date of birth)

Tags: python, pandas

How can I calculate the age of a person (based off the dob column) and add a column to the dataframe with the new value?

dataframe looks like the following:

```
    lname      fname     dob
0    DOE       LAURIE    03011979
1    BOURNE    JASON     06111978
2    GRINCH    XMAS      12131988
3    DOE       JOHN      11121986
```

I tried doing the following:

```
now = datetime.now()
df1['age'] = now - df1['dob']
```

But, received the following error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
import datetime as DT
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = 'warn'

content = '''     ssno        lname         fname    pos_title             ser  gender  dob 
0    23456789    PLILEY     JODY        BUDG ANAL             0560  F      031871 
1    987654321   NOEL       HEATHER     PRTG SRVCS SPECLST    1654  F      120852
2    234567891   SONJU      LAURIE      SUPVY CONTR SPECLST   1102  F      010999
3    345678912   MANNING    CYNTHIA     SOC SCNTST            0101  F      081692
4    456789123   NAUERTZ    ELIZABETH   OFF AUTOMATION ASST   0326  F      031387'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(content), sep='\s{2,}')
df['dob'] = df['dob'].apply('{:06}'.format)

now = pd.Timestamp('now')
df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob'], format='%m%d%y')    # 1
df['dob'] = df['dob'].where(df['dob'] < now, df['dob'] -  np.timedelta64(100, 'Y'))   # 2
df['age'] = (now - df['dob']).astype('<m8[Y]')    # 3
print(df)
```

yields

```
        ssno    lname      fname            pos_title   ser gender  \
0   23456789   PLILEY       JODY            BUDG ANAL   560      F   
1  987654321     NOEL    HEATHER   PRTG SRVCS SPECLST  1654      F   
2  234567891    SONJU     LAURIE  SUPVY CONTR SPECLST  1102      F   
3  345678912  MANNING    CYNTHIA           SOC SCNTST   101      F   
4  456789123  NAUERTZ  ELIZABETH  OFF AUTOMATION ASST   326      F   

                  dob  age  
0 1971-03-18 00:00:00   43  
1 1952-12-08 18:00:00   61  
2 1999-01-09 00:00:00   15  
3 1992-08-16 00:00:00   22  
4 1987-03-13 00:00:00   27
```

---

1. It looks like your `dob` column are currently strings. First,
   convert them to `Timestamps` using `pd.to_datetime`.
2. The format `'%m%d%y'` converts the last two digits to years, but
   unfortunately assumes `52` means 2052. Since that's probably not
   Heather Noel's birthyear, let's subtract 100 years from `dob`
   whenever the `dob` is greater than `now`. You may want to subtract a few years to `now` in the condition `df['dob'] < now` since it may be slightly more likely to have a 101 year old worker than a 1 year old worker...
3. You can subtract`dob` from `now` to obtain [timedelta64[ns]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic). To
   convert that to years, use `astype('<m8[Y]')` or `astype('timedelta64[Y]')`.

Comment: I get the following error from the code above when running in a .py file.  What does this mean
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  df1['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['dob'], format='%m%d%y')
c:\users\davidl~1\appdata\local\temp\1\tmpxt4mqz.py:37: 
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
  df1['dob'] = df1['dob'].where(df1['dob'] < now, df1['dob'] -  np.timedelta64(100, 'Y'))

Comment: That warning is not an error, but it is a warning that the code *may* be assigning to a copy of the data rather than the original data in the DataFrame. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21463854/190597) and [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail). I think it is a false alarm in the context of the code above, but I am uncertain why you are seeing the warning at all, since when I run the code above I see no warning. When you run the code above, do you see the warning?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm getting a  ValueError with the code above.

Comment: in ipython the original code works great.  When creating a function in a .py file it gives me the error.

Comment: Can you post a few lines of `eeprofil.txt` so the error you are seeing (is it a ValueError or the SettingWithCopyWarning?) is reproducible?

Comment: When I run your code on the CSV data you posted, I get the correct result with no errors.

Comment: I cleaned up my original code so that the date comes across as four digit years.  Maybe this will help.

Comment: @coldspeed: Thanks for the suggested improvements, but I think there are two problems with using `pd.compat.StringIO`. (1) In Python2 `pd.compat.StringIO` points to `StringIO.StringIO`. But in Python2, `pd.read_table` expects `BytesIO`, not `StringIO`. (2) The [API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html) warns that `pd.compat` is private, and its functionality is not guaranteed. I'd be willing to overlook (2), but (1) is a deal-breaker.

Comment: @unutbu I was updating this to work with more recent versions of pandas. Read table seems to be deprecated in 0.24, so I changed the function to `read_csv`, which I don't think has a problem reading `StringIO` input... I could be mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I agree at this point I'd rather support Python3. So I've changed the code to simply use `io.StringIO`. Changing `read_table` to `read_csv` is a good change too (thank you for that).

Comment: I don't have a Python2 with pandas to test this out on anymore, but if I recall correctly, both `read_table` and `read_csv` need `BytesIO` and raise some error if passed `StringIO`.

Comment: Point 3 is no longer supported in Pandas 2.0 [from what I read](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html?highlight=sum#construction-with-datetime64-or-timedelta64-dtype-with-unsupported-resolution) - gives `ValueError: Cannot convert from timedelta64[ns] to timedelta64[Y]. Supported resolutions are 's', 'ms', 'us', 'ns'`

Answer (score 19):

I found easier solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

d = {'col0': [1, 2, 6], 
     'col1': [3, 8, 3], 
     'col2': ['17.02.1979', '11.11.1993', '01.08.1961']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def calculate_age(born):
    born = datetime.strptime(born, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

df['age'] = df['col6'].apply(calculate_age)
print(df)
```

output:

```
     col0  col1  col3        age
0       1     3  17.02.1979   39
1       2     8  11.11.1993   24
2       6     3  01.08.1961   57
```

Comment: won't work correctly with this date for instance '20-03-2020'

Answer (score 7):

```
# Data setup
df

    lname   fname        dob
0     DOE  LAURIE 1979-03-01
1  BOURNE   JASON 1978-06-11
2  GRINCH    XMAS 1988-12-13
3     DOE    JOHN 1986-11-12

# Make sure to parse all datetime columns in advance
df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob'], errors='coerce')
```

If you want only the year portion of the age, use [@unutbu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26789573/4909087). . .

```
now = pd.to_datetime('now')
now
# Timestamp('2019-04-14 00:00:43.105892')

(now - df['dob']).astype('<m8[Y]') 

0    40.0
1    40.0
2    30.0
3    32.0
Name: dob, dtype: float64
```

Another option is to subtract the year portion and account for the month difference using

```
(now.year - df['dob'].dt.year) - ((now.month - df['dob'].dt.month) < 0)

0    40
1    40
2    30
3    32
Name: dob, dtype: int64
```

---

If you want the (almost) precise age (including the fractional portion), query `total_seconds` and divide.

```
(now - df['dob']).dt.total_seconds() / (60*60*24*365.25)

0    40.120446
1    40.840501
2    30.332630
3    32.418872
Name: dob, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this one liner when you are trying to find the age from date of birth column with current year

```
import pandas as pd

df["dob"] = pd.to_datetime(data["dob"])

df["age"] = df["dob"].apply(lambda x : (pd.datetime.now().year - x.year))
```

Answer (score 2):

First thought is that your years are two digit, which is a not great choice in this day and age. In any case, I'm going to assume that all years like `05` are actually `1905`. This is probably not correct(!) but coming up with the right rule is going to depend a lot on your data.

```
from datetime import date

def age(date1, date2):
    naive_yrs = date2.year - date1.year
    if date1.replace(year=date2.year) > date2:
        correction = -1
    else:
        correction = 0
    return naive_yrs + correction

df1['age'] = df1['dob'].map(lambda x: age(date(int('19' + x[-2:]), int(x[:2]), int(x[2:-2])), date.today()))
```

Comment: unutbu's answer will definitely be faster than mine, since it uses numpy date magicks that I haven't bothered to learn.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following solution:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df1['age'] = [relativedelta(pd.to_datetime('now'), d).years for d in df1['dob']]
```

Answer (score 0):

once you have the year, month, and day part of DOB separated, you can use the below-given lines to get age in no. of years and months.

```
tmpdf = df[['born_year','born_month','born_day']].copy()
tmpdf.columns = ["year", "month", "day"]
df['dob']=pd.to_datetime(tmpdf , errors='coerce')
df['age_y']=(datetime.today()-df['dob']).dt.days/365.25
df['age_y']=df['age_y'].astype(int)
df['age_m']=((datetime.today()-df['dob']).dt.days/365.25 -  df['age_y'] ) * 12
df['age_m']=df['age_m'].astype(int)
```