# How to convert a date to different format in Python to calculate age

Tags: pandas, datetime, formatting, data-conversion

I have a dataframe df with a DOB (date of birth) that is in the format of `"Year-Month-Day (1994-01-01)"` and the DOB variable is an object.
I need to assign age to each person using this DOB variable. I noticed I need to use `datetime` to find age, and I need to convert the format to `"Year/Month/Day (1994/01/01)"` first.

I wonder if someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post an example input and your expected output. `"Year-Month-Day" ` can mean various things (`99-03-02` or `1999-3-2`?)

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I just edited as you mentioned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas get the age from a date (example: date of birth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788854/pandas-get-the-age-from-a-date-example-date-of-birth) -> see esp. [cs95's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55670911/10197418).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
now = pd.Timestamp('now')
df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob'])  
df['age'] = (now - df['dob']).astype('<m8[Y]')    
print(df)
```

covert your str into datetime objects

You can subtract dob from now to obtain timedelta64[ns]. To convert that to years, use astype('

for your last formatting

`df['dob'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))`

Comment: for converting the format I ran your code and got this error: ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'```

Comment: `strftime` is string from time which is a datetime attribute so first convert it into datetime using the above code then use it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked and I wonder what ```m8[Y]``` does? and if this way gives me the exact age or just subtracting ```current year``` from the ```birth year``` and ignoring ```day and month```?

Comment: to convert to years use astype('<m8[Y]') or astype('timedelta64[Y]')

Comment: I mean if this part : ```now - df['dob']``` calculates the exact age?