# Can't edit dataframe data through iloc in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, copy

So something really weird is happening when I try editing :

```
In [119]: print(GDP.iloc[1][0])
Out [119]: Andorra
```

When I try to edit it with `.iloc` and query it again this happens:

```
In [120]: GDP.iloc[1][0]="Cats"
          print(GDP.iloc[1][0])
Out [120]: Andorra
```

I remember reading that `.iloc` may call a copy or an image depending on the `numpy` type. Anyway to fix this or is there other way I should be editing my data? Thanks.

Comment: Try `GDP.iloc[1,0]=`? `GDP.iloc[1][0]` is probably making a copy thus rendering it not editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to avoid chaining assignments in pandas, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments)
which refers to this Pandas doc about [chaining assignments](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

Whenever, you have "][" in pandas it is generally bad and should be rewritten.

It is best written as Divakar suggests:

```
GDP.iloc[1,0]="Cats"
```