# Why am I not able to store my value at the given location

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    train[train.enrollee_id==a[i]]['enrolled_university']=train[train.enrollee_id==a[i]]['enrolled_university'].fillna(y_pred[I],inlace=True)
    print(train[train.enrollee_id==a[i]]['enrolled_university’])
```

112   NaN

Name: enrolled_university, dtype: float64

191   NaN

Name: enrolled_university, dtype: float64

244   NaN

Name: enrolled_university, dtype: float64

284   NaN

Name: enrolled_university, dtype: float64

315   NaN

Name: enrolled_university, dtype: float64

401   NaN

Name: enrolled_university, dtype: float64

Comment: First off you are using chaining... this is a big "no-no" in pandas.  You can quickly recognize chaining when you see this "] \[", there are other ways to select locations in pandas dataframes. [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=chaining#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments)

Comment: ok,I am understanding that what you are trying to say @ScottBoston but can you tell then what should I do to store my value at my desired location as I have  a conditional statement also, I am a bit newbie at this and your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @VaibhavSka this is why Scott posted a link to the documentation...