# fillna doesn't give the desired result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to substitute NaTs in a pandas dataframe.

```
orders.PAID_AT

0                       NaT
1                       NaT
2                       NaT
3                       NaT
4                       NaT
6                       NaT
7                       NaT
8                       NaT
9                       NaT
10                      NaT
11      2018-08-04 16:19:10
12      2018-08-04 16:19:10
13                      NaT
14                      NaT
15      2018-08-04 13:49:08
16      2018-08-04 13:49:08
18                      NaT
19                      NaT
20                      NaT
21      2018-08-04 12:41:48
```

The rows 0..10 need to be filled with value of row 11 etc. Somehow I can't get it right with:

```
orders.PAID_AT.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
```

I'm getting the same result as above. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think need `orders.PAID_AT = orders.PAID_AT.bfill()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For avoid [chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments/21463854#21463854) assign back:

```
orders.PAID_AT = orders.PAID_AT.bfill()
```