# How to replace values in a column in pandas using regex and a conditional

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to replace certain values in a pandas column (dataframe) using regex, but I want to apply the regex based on values in another column.

A basic example;

```
index  col1  col2
1      yes   foobar
2      yes   foo
3      no    foobar
```

Using the following;

```
df.loc[df['col1'] == 'yes', 'col2'].replace({r'(fo)o(?!bar)' :r'\1'}, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

I expected the following result;

```
index  col1  col2
1      yes   foobar
2      yes   fo
3      no    foobar
```

However it doesn't seem to be working? It doesn't throw any errors or a `settingwithcopy` warning, it just does nothing. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For avoid [chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments/21463854#21463854) assign back and remove `inplace=True`:

```
mask = df['col1'] == 'yes'
df.loc[mask, 'col2'] = df.loc[mask, 'col2'].replace({r'(fo)o(?!bar)' :r'\1'}, regex=True)

print (df)
  col1    col2
1  yes  foobar
2  yes      fo
3   no  foobar
```

Comment: Thank you jez, as always. Will accept when it allows me

Comment: Is there any reason to be using the `DataFrame.replace` method @Nordle? It seems that `df['col2'] = df.col2[df.col1 == 'yes'].str.replace('(fo)o(?!bar)', r'\1')` would suit your purposes here...

Comment: @JonClements what's the difference between the 2 Jon? But no there is no particular reason I'm using `df.replace`

Comment: @Nordle `df.replace` can be used to replace multiple columns at once with regexes or just translate one value to another using mappings... if you're just replacing a string in a single column, it's better to use `Series.str.replace` as above... jezrael may offer his opinion on that, but `df.replace` is a sledge hammer to crack a nut here...

Comment: (and would be correctly be written along the lines of `df.replace({'col2': '(fo)o(?!bar)'}, r'\1', regex=True)` - might be an idea to read the docs for both and note the differences.

Comment: @JonClements thank you for the info, I've had a look at yes it seems using replace is overkill here. I've switched to a series replacement based on the suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where`:

```
df.assign(
    col2=np.where(df.col1.eq('yes'), df.col2.str.replace(r'(fo)o(?!bar)', r'\1'), df.col2)
)
```

```
  col1    col2
1  yes  foobar
2  yes      fo
3   no  foobar
```