# Replace letter in string pandas

Tags: pandas

I have this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['ID','Data']
data = [['26A20',123],
        ['12A20',123],
        ['23A20',123]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=columns)

>>df
      ID  Data
0  26A20   123
1  12A20   123
2  23A20   123
```

And a simple task, to remove the A:s from ID when ID starts with 26 or 23:

```
df.loc[df['ID'].str.startswith(('23','26'))]['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace('A','')
```

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

And nothing Changes:

```
>>df
      ID  Data
0  26A20   123
1  12A20   123
2  23A20   123
```

Im using loc, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove double `][` for avoid [chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments/21463854#21463854):

```
df.loc[df['ID'].str.startswith(('23','26')), 'ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace('A','')
print (df)
      ID  Data
0   2620   123
1  12A20   123
2   2320   123
```

Also is possible filter in both sides for reduce execute of function `replace`:

```
mask = df['ID'].str.startswith(('23','26'))
df.loc[mask, 'ID'] = df.loc[mask, 'ID'].str.replace('A','')
print (df)
      ID  Data
0   2620   123
1  12A20   123
2   2320   123
```

Answer (score 1):

And there is `np.where()` approach:

```
df['ID'] = np.where(df['ID'].str.startswith(('23','26')), df['ID'].str.replace('A', ''), df['ID'])
```