# .iloc & fillna - inplace=True vs inplace=False

Tags: python, pandas

Just out of curiosity I would like to have a quick explanation of the following "issue".

When I did this:

```
data_ogd.iloc[:, 3:10].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

nothing changed at my dataframe columns and I still had the NAs at these columns.

But when I did this:

```
data_ogd.iloc[:, 3:10] = data_ogd.iloc[:, 3:10].fillna(value=0)
```

The NAs were filled with 0s.

Why was this happening?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21463854/2901002) for explanation, same principe - chain assignment of Series, sometimes warning, sometimes not.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael . Ah ok yes it is this common issue. By the way, I did not receive any warning this time.

Comment: It depends of version of pandas, I guess in old version it should be warning.

Comment: @jezrael, ok cool. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes it works as well (when I tried with version 0.23.0)