# How to apply fillna to last N columns of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a data frame with many columns. I would like to fill the nan's with 0's for the last x number of columns. I used the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
df.iloc[:, -10:-1].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

What am I doing wrong? when I specifically refer to a column by name:

```
df['column_a'].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

it works, but I'd rather not do it one column at a time.

Comment: this should work, can you provide a data sample?

Comment: This is an almost duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134012/pandas-dataframe-fillna-only-some-columns-in-place you can find loads of useful variants there.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the posting you mentioned is referring to the columns by name. My question was referring to the columns by position backward. As I mentioned in my original question, my code works when I referred to the columns by specific names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recipe that should work here is

```
df.iloc[:, -x:] = df.iloc[:, -x:].fillna(value=0)
```

A reproducible example here is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(10),
                   'col2':range(1, 11), 
                   'col3':range(2, 12),
                   'col4':range(3, 13),
                   'col5':range(4, 14)})

# pepper with NaNs
df.iloc[8, 2] = None
df.iloc[8, 3] = None
df.iloc[8, 4] = None

# apply fillna change to last 2 cols
x = 2
df.iloc[:, -x:] = df.iloc[:, -x:].fillna(value=0)

print(df)
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why doesn't 'inplace=True' work?

Comment: I'd refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744015/iloc-fillna-inplace-true-vs-inplace-false and links therein! As far as I understand, that inplace is updating a copy and not the original `df`