# Why does pandas fillna() inplace does not work for multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using this data set: [Titanic pasengers](https://www.openml.org/data/get_csv/16826755/phpMYEkMl)
I am trying to fill in missing categorical data but the `fillna()` with the `inplace` option does not do anything:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://www.openml.org/data/get_csv/16826755/phpMYEkMl')

# replace question marks with np.nan
data = data.replace('?', np.nan)

var_categor = ['sex', 'cabin', 'embarked' ] 

data.loc[:, var_categor].fillna("Missing", inplace=True)
```

I get the same number of nan values:

```
data[var_categor].isnull().sum()
```

I get no error messages, no warnings, it just doesnt do anything. Is this normal behavior? Shouldn't it give a warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744015/iloc-fillna-inplace-true-vs-inplace-false

Comment: Yes this is normal behaviour. `data.loc[:, var_categor]` creates a copy `inplace` affects only that copy. Since there are no references to the object it is no longer accessible. It does not give a warning because almost all levels of pandas [discourage the use of inplace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384/15497888), and eventually it will be removed from all methods which is why development on implementing warnings  are not implemented the same way chained expressions are with [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/15497888).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to chain operations and return a copy of values rather than modify `inplace`:

```
data[var_categor] = data.replace('?', np.nan)[var_categor].fillna('Missing')
```

```
>>> data[var_categor].isna().sum()
sex         0
cabin       0
embarked    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hello. Yes I know I can do that but why is it no working? Is it normal behavior it just does't?

Comment: No it's not a normal behavior because the option exists but does not work as expected. `inplace` parameter should be remove (I hope). You can read [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45570984/15239951) to know more.

Answer (score 1):

It’s likely an issue with getting a view/slice/copy of the dataframe, and setting things in-place on that object.

The trivial fix is to not use `inplace` of course:

```
data[var_categor] = data[var_categor].fillna("Missing")
```

An alternate way is to use `.fillna` directly on the object. Here if you want to limit which columns are filled, a dictionary mapping columns to replacement values can be used:

```
>>> data.fillna({var: 'Missing' for var in var_categor}, inplace=True)
>>> data[var_categor].isna().sum()
sex         0
cabin       0
embarked    0
dtype: int64
```

However best practice in pandas is to avoid `inplace`, see [the github issue that discusses deprecating it](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) for more detail.