# Python Fill in column values based on ID

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to fill in the na values in 'Col' by the ID number.
I have tried groupby

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,1,2,1,2],
    'Col':['One','NaN','NaN','Two','NaN','NaN']
})
```

This is the expected output:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,1,2,1,2],
    'Col':['One','Two','One','Two','One','Two']
})
```

I know this is an easy example but I would appreciate any help you could give me. Also I have a dataframe with 1 million rows so anything that would be time efficient would be appreciated

What I have tried:

```
x=df_total[df_total['id'].astype(str)=='2']
buck_map = dict(x[~x['buckets'].isnull()][['id','buckets']].values)
x['buckets']=x['id'].map(buck_map)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill Na in multiple columns with values from another column within the pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303445/fill-na-in-multiple-columns-with-values-from-another-column-within-the-pandas-da)

Comment: Note ; you do not have NaN values in your sample; you have strings of `'NaN'`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help

Comment: Please clean up your example (no strings `'NaN'`) and also describe what you want to happen in the case there are conflicting values of `Col` for a given `ID`. If you believe there is never, ever such conflicting values, I'd advise you to be defensive and `assert` so. Data is _most of the time_ messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary mapping ID values to fill values:

```
fill_dict = df.groupby('ID')['Col'].last().to_dict()
```

then replace NaN values with fill values using the dictionary:

```
df['Col'] = df['Col'].fillna(df['ID'].map(fill_dict))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you really want and if it is just a translation and substitution or if groupby is needed. Assumining you mean strings for the column and that you want just a substitution then you need a way of translating such as 1 to 'One' (a Dictionary is ideal) and then applying this to each row.  You can use:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,1,2,1,2],
    'Col':['One','NaN','NaN','Two','NaN','NaN']
})

def func(row):
    d= {0: 'zero', 1:'One', 2:'Two'}
    if row['Col'] == 'NaN':
        val = d[row['ID']]
    else:
        val = row['Col']
    return val
 
df['Col'] = df.apply(func, axis = 1)

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
   ID  Col
0   1  One
1   2  Two
2   1  One
3   2  Two
4   1  One
5   2  Two
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous, as there are several ways to produce the desired output based on your example.

Assuming that you are looking for the "majority value" per `ID`, and also that the `NaN`s are actual `float('NaN')` and to be dropped, and not just the string `'NaN'`, then the following would be quite efficient:

```py
def majority(s):
    return s.mode()[0]

newdf = df.assign(Col=df.groupby('ID')['Col'].transform(majority))

>>> newdf
   ID  Col
0   1  One
1   2  Two
2   1  One
3   2  Two
4   1  One
5   2  Two
```

Note: to make sure the `'NaN'` are nan and not strings, do this first:

```py
df = df.assign(Col=df['Col'].replace({'NaN': float('Nan')}))
```