# pandas replace is not replacing value even with inplace=True

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this. I would like to replace marital_status `'Missing'` with `'Married'` if `'no_of_children'` is not `nan`.

```
>cust_data_df[['marital_status','no_of_children']]
>

    marital_status  no_of_children

0   Married           NaN
1   Married           NaN
2   Missing            1
3   Missing            2
4   Single            NaN
5   Single            NaN
6   Married           NaN
7   Single            NaN
8   Married           NaN
9   Married           NaN
10  Single            NaN
```

This is what I tried:

```
cust_data_df.loc[cust_data_df['no_of_children'].notna()==True, 'marital_status'].replace({'Missing':'Married'},inplace=True)
```

But this is not doing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign back replaced values for avoid [chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments/21463854#21463854):

```
m = cust_data_df['no_of_children'].notna()
d = {'Missing':'Married'}
cust_data_df.loc[m, 'marital_status'] = cust_data_df.loc[m, 'marital_status'].replace(d)
```

If need set all values:

```
cust_data_df.loc[m, 'marital_status'] = 'Married'
```

EDIT:

Thanks @Quickbeam2k1 for explanation:

> **cust_data_df.loc[cust_data_df['no_of_children'].notna()==True, 'marital_status']** is just a new object which has no reference. Replacing there, will leave the original object unchanged

Comment: Maybe some more explanation: `cust_data_df.loc[cust_data_df['no_of_children'].notna()==True, 'marital_status']`  is just a new object which has no reference. Replacing there, will leave the original object unchanged