# Blank space to_string output

Tags: python, string, pandas, tostring

when i pass to_string  to a filter dataframe this generates a blank space in the output,
I need the string without spaces.

this is the code:

```
df2['ETS'][df2['APPOINTMENT'] == appointment].to_string(index=False)
```

output:

```
' 10/19/2019'
```

[image: output]

Comment: Try `df2.loc[df2['APPOINTMENT'] == appointment, 'ETS'].str.strip().to_string(index=False)` or `df2.loc[df2['APPOINTMENT'] == appointment, 'ETS'].to_string(index=False).strip()`

Comment: Avoid chained assignments. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments

Comment: This space might be coming from the source data. If it is unavoidable or can't control the source then do what cs95 proposes

Comment: @cs95 .strip() works great!!, but now how i can delete the ' ' of the output: '10/19/2019'

Comment: @salem1992 IPython will print out the repr by default (including the quotes), wrap the entire expression within `print(...)` and it will print the string without quotes.