# Not able to add missing values using fillna() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I am trying to add missing values to a column after filtering with a condition using fillna() method. It fills and shows the values but does not update in the dataframe. Tried using the inplace parameter as well.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
csm[csm.Make == "Maruti"]["Odometer (KM)"].fillna(csm[csm.Make == "Maruti"]["Odometer (KM)"].mean(), inplace = True)
```

Please help me with the solution on how to fix this issue!

Answer (score 2):

You can add [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for change columns in DataFrame, not `Series` and for avoid [chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments/21463854#21463854) assign back and remove `inplace=True`:

```
m = csm.Make == "Maruti"
csm[m, "Odometer (KM)"] = csm[m, "Odometer (KM)"].fillna(csm[m, "Odometer (KM)"].mean())
```