# Replacing values in Pandas dataframe using .replace and associated warning

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas dataframe `datainput` has 4 columns namely `COLUMN1`, `COLUMN2`,`COLUMN3`, `COLUMN4` each with values of `Yes` or `No`.
I am trying to replace "Yes" and "No" values in a pandas dataframe with 1 and 2 using the following code

```
datainput.COLUMN1.replace(("Yes","No"),(1,0),inplace=True)
datainput.COLUMN2.replace(("Yes","No"),(1,0),inplace=True)
datainput.COLUMN3.replace(("Yes","No"),(1,0),inplace=True)
datainput.COLUMN4.replace(("Yes","No"),(1,0),inplace=True)
```

I am getting it successfully converted but I am getting an associated warning.

```
C:\Users\mmpra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:6786: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)
```

**How to avoid the warning and what does it mean?**

Comment: `datainput = datainput.copy()` before any manipulation of `datainput` will remove the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning.

Comment: @QuangHoang this did work. What is the logic?

Comment: details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing that `caveat` because the slice/index of the  dataframe is returning either a view, or a copy. This warning was created to flag "chained assignment" operations.

You can suppress it by creating a `deepcopy` of the dataframe:

```
datainput = datainput.copy(deep=True)
```

It's always nicer to use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in such cases. Take this for example:

```
In [1685]: import numpy as np

In [1686]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Yes', 'No'], 'B':['Yes', 'Yes']})
In [1687]: df
Out[1687]: 
     A    B
0  Yes  Yes
1   No  Yes

In [1690]: df['A'] = np.where(df['A'].eq('Yes'), 1, 0)
In [1691]: df['B'] = np.where(df['B'].eq('Yes'), 1, 0) 

In [1692]: df
Out[1692]: 
   A  B
0  0  1
1  0  1
```

No warnings in this case will arise.

Comment: This won't solve the problem mentioned in OP's post. Your data is not a copy/slice of any other.

Comment: Agreed. But, it's better to use `np.where` in these cases. Won't you agree.

Comment: Not necessarily true. Although I don't know if that `replace` command will work, but for example it won't replace values other than `Yes` an `No`, e.g. `NaN`, while `np.where` will. That said, the main question is why the warning, not how to do things.

Comment: @QuangHoang I've put the explanation answering OP's question. Sorry for missing it earlier.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Thanks for the explanation. Can you please elaborate a bit more on `deep` and `chained assignment` . If I am viewing the copy that means the main data frame (before replacement), is still there but hidden???

Comment: @QuangHoang How np.where will replace the NaN?

Comment: Hey @PraveenKumar-M. For details regarding `chained assignments`, please follow this [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments). `Deepcopy` is basically the concept where any changes made to a copy of object do not reflect in the original object. Hence in your case, if you create a deepcopy, original df will remain unaffected and no warning will appear.