# I am trying to assign a value to a cell in a dataframe using iloc and it is not working. It is simply staying its original value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Trying to change 174.0 to NaN. Am I missing something obvious? Finding the index of the value in the overall dataframe is too complicated, so I narrowed it down to Well L15. Is this not allowd?

```
input: df[df['Well']=='L15'].iloc[4,6]
output: 174.0

input: df[df['Well']=='L15'].iloc[4,6] = np.nan 

input: df[df['Well']=='L15'].iloc[4,6]
output: 174.0
```

I expect this to give me NaN at the end, not 174.0.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting a [`SettingWithCopy Warning`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21463589/14627505) by any chance? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=chained#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=chained#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) say:

> Outside of simple cases, it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees)

So in your case, it is hard to predict, will `df[df['Well']=='L15'].iloc[4,6]` be a

- *view* (in which case changing its elements would change the **original** elements since it is only a **view**),
- or a *copy* (in which case **its** elements would be changed, but the original elements would **not**.)

Here is a workaround that you could use. Create a copy explicitly (so that pandas doesn't complain for not knowing if it's a view or a copy), change the value in this copy, and then replace the values in the original:

```py
sub_df = df[df['Well']=='L15'].copy()

sub_df.iloc[4, 6] = np.nan 
df[df['Well']=='L15'] = sub_df
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is beautiful and it works perfectly, problem solved!